# Number of samples to estimate Cauchy probability distribution?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics, fitting, cauchy-distribution

I wonder how many samples (approximately) are needed to fit the parameters of a Cauchy probability distribution. I'm guessing probably more than with a normal.

Comment: How many samples do you need for a Normal distribution?

Comment: As a rough rule, 20 to 50 is fine.

Comment: What is the basis for the 20 to 50 ? What calculations are being applied to derive it? Xi'an's question was not designed to elicit an arbitrary number (unless all you seek is an arbitrary number that doesn't necessarily achieve anything in particular, for that, "20 to 50" should do fine) - but to get you to think about what you're asking for. If you specify something about the accuracy of the parameter estimates we might be able to begin to formulate a more useful answer.

Comment: @Glen_b Mostly empirical. My teacher said it usually works well.

Comment: Yikes. Let me give you an example. Lets say I want to know the mean height of a population to about the nearest mm (let's pretend it's approximately normally distributed for the present so you have something to compare with your 20 to 50). I will need a *much* larger sample than if I only wanted to know the mean height to about the nearest cm. It could well be (depending on the standard deviation) that say 10 or so might be enough for the second case but then about 1000 would be needed for the first.

Comment: @Glen_b Makes sense to me.

Comment: So to do something other than just giving you some arbitrary number that mightn't achieve what you need we would need some approximate sense of the required accuracy of the parameters (or some other way of pinning down accuracy - such as on the estimated cdf). Typically you might do something like specify a [margin of error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margin_of_error) (interval half-width) on the scale and/or location parameters and an associated coverage probability ("confidence"). Or whatever other quantity you need (e.g. if you need a certain accuracy on say the lower quartile)

Comment: Alternatively, if we had a clear sense of what the "20 to 50" is actually supposed to achieve we might be able to emulate that.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is 3 [rather than 42](https://hitchhikers.fandom.com/wiki/42). Indeed, the maximum likelihood estimate of $(\mu,\sigma)$, the location and scale of the Cauchy, is available for $n=3$ observations, as shown in this 1978 note of [Ferguson](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2286549?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents). (For $n=2$, the MLE is not unique.)

Comment: Why is the MLE needed?  Cannot one (easily) estimate the parameters using a different procedure, such as relating them to the median and MAD?  (The question concerning how *good* such a procedure might be is separate from whether it's *possible* to estimate the parameters from two values.)

Comment: @whuber: my answer is somewhat sarcastic, I am afraid! It is even possible to estimate the parameters with no observation, $\hat\mu=1056$ and $\hat\sigma=3.14$ are acceptable estimators as well.